# Does the Power Users concept exist in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I need to give few special privileges to a group of Users in Windows 7.

I could have done it with ease in XP through the "**Power Users**" group.

How would I do the same in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

The Power Users group exists on Vista and Windows 7, just as it did on XP. So the answer is you do it just the same as you did on XP.

Comment: You can access those group settings via Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Local Users and Groups. As a shortcut run `lusrmgr.msc`.

Comment: But User(normal user) doesn't have any permission to install (modify program files) even after adding to poweruser group,

Comment: Then grant whatever privileges you want to that group. Or create your own group and set the privileges as you desire.

Comment: How to do that? I mean how to set privileges to Power Users Group?

Comment: It seems power user group is there in win7 only for backward compatibility ....
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/5642-63-windows-power-user-user-permissions

Comment: it is there, but only for backward compatibility. the power group is no longer used since Vista

Answer (score 0):

I'd first decide the context of the situation.  If they are gonna get admin priviledges, which essential what the power user group was, they need to be treated like admins.  This means proper audits of their admin and user logins along with their workstations.

If you just need to delegate privileges, then do that.  Save yourself a headache with proper planning.